# Soap after converting php cli to cgi

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

i wrote a web-service that it works correctly on my previous server but after changing my server i have a problem with php cli and i converted cli to cgi and after that when a client connected to my web-service shows this error for him:

i didn't change my code only change my server

XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 2: Mismatched tag

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

the problem is this character of utf-8 before php tag and make problem for parse xml:

```
ï»¿
```

so dont save your file in utf-8 format

Comment: Save in utf-8, just don't add the BOM (utf-8 doesn't need a BOM contrary to utf-16).